# How to send parameters for get request using retrofit and kotlin Coroutines.?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I was following the tutorial from 
https://proandroiddev.com/suspend-what-youre-doing-retrofit-has-now-coroutines-support-c65bd09ba067.
I am having difficulty to understand how to send parameters to get request from MainActivity

Webservice.kt

```
interface Webservice {
@GET("/todos/{id}")
suspend fun getTodo(@Path(value = "id") todoId: Int): Todo
}
```

TodoRepository.kt

```
class TodoRepository {
var client: Webservice = RetrofitClient.webservice
suspend fun getTodo(id: Int) = client.getTodo(id)
}
```

MainViewModel.kt

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
val repository: TodoRepository = TodoRepository()

val firstTodo = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val retrivedTodo = repository.getTodo(1)

    emit(retrivedTodo)
    }
}
```

MainAcitvity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

    showFirstTodo()
}

private fun showFirstTodo() {
    viewModel.getFirstTodo().observe(this, Observer {
        titleTextView.text = it.title
    })
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your viewModel code something like this

```
 private val _todo = MutableLiveData<Todo>()
 val todo : LiveData<Todo> get() =_todo

 //Call this method from activity
 fun getTodo(arg : Int)
 {
  val result = //Call Coroutines here
  _todo.postValue(result)
 }
```

Comment: i did something like this  
`fun getTodo(arg : String):LiveData<Response<com.example.myapplication.entity.UserData>>
    {
        val result = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val retrivedTodo = repository.getTodo(arg)

            emit(retrivedTodo)
        }

        return result
    }`
Is it a correct way?

Comment: If you want to get todo only once then I guess it's okay....on conditions like todo refresh it's not okay because you cannot use the live data you just created

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `Path` and `Query` in `GET` request.
You can easily pass query string like this:

```
interface Webservice {

    @GET("/todos/{id}")
    suspend fun getTodo(@Path(value = "id") todoId: Int, @Query("name") name: String?): Todo
    }
```

Comment: i am sending a constant value 1 from MainViewModel , i need to send a variable that is entered in text box in UI

Comment: How to pass multiple parameters to GET request ?

Comment: If you are using a query,<br> `suspend fun getTodo(@Query(value = "id") todoId: Int, @Query("name") name: String?): Todo
` and if you are using a path way <br>
`suspend fun getTodo(@Path(value = "id") todoId: Int, @Path("name") name: String?): Todo
`